# Apply a simple CMS to a front end HTML/CSS layout

Tags: html, css, content-management-system

I have a specific front-end demo `(https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/b6c2ayeg/)` that I want to make into a dynamic site that I can update through a CMS where what gets populated in the sliders (see demo) is all coming from a CMS / google Sheet even.

I've never worked on the backend/CMS – what's the easiest or simplest CMS I can attach to this? Any tutorials/videos would be very helpful

thank you!